# Does Openshift v2 supports Rolling Updates for scaled applications

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

How can I do rolling updates/deployments in a scaled application in Openshift v2?

I know I can access the container (via ssh) and fire a 'gear rotate-out'. But how to push my new version (deployment) to a specific container (Gear)? Can Openshift do this automatically?

When I push an update to a scaled application all the Gears are updated at same time? Is the update transparent to the end users?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do rolling updates on OpenShift Online unless you were to write your own script or cartridge to take care of it.  You should try using the hot_deploy marker file, this keeps the application running while the new code is deployed.